# How to make a copy of a plotly figure object?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

How do you copy a plotly figure object in order to make a few changes but keep the same basic structure for other plots?

The following raises an Attribute error:

**Code:**

```
fig2=fig1.copy()
```

**Error:**

> AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'copy'

And of course `fig2=fig1` will not help because both names will point to the same object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like the error message says, `fig1` or `go.Figure()` does not have a copy functionality or attribute. The solution is easy though; just make another plotly object using `go.Figure()` directly on your existing `fig1`:

```
fig2 = go.Figure(fig1)
```

Here's an example where you make a copy of `fig1` named `fig2`, and add a title to `fig2` only.

Of course this makes a lot more sense for more complex figures.

**Code 1:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig1 = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
fig1.show()
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
fig2=go.Figure(fig1)
fig2['layout']['title']['text']='Figure2'
fig2.show()
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]

And just to make sure that fig1 is left alone:

**Code 3:**

```
fig1.show()
```

**Plot 3:**

[image]

Comment: Hey sir, In code2 why to set :: fig2['layout']['title']['text']='Figure2' instead only fig2['title']?

Comment: @Codenewbie I don't think you can do anything with just `fig2['title']`. Or can you?

Comment: I was thinking about the title which(only) has to be changed and the rest we just get from fig1 , so Im worried why to using all three.....Am I correct sir? or missing something?

Comment: I'm sending you an invitation to chat.